# How to add GTK Theme Preference on Gnome 2 using FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

GTK Theme Preferences is available in the Shimmer Project PPA for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin and 12.10 Quantal Quetzal. Add the PPA and install it using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shimmerproject/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config
```

The commands are for Linux system and I have a FreeBSD System . So my question is how can I istall on FreeBSD ?

Comment: Get the source for it (https://github.com/satya164/gtk-theme-config) , then compile under FreeBSD. I didn't try it, but I think it works.

Comment: Just modify ~/.gtkrc-2.0 ...

Answer (score 0):

You should at least check if GhostBSD have not already solved this - they seem to work a lot on gnome+FreeBSD: http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ghostbsd